# Limit of jumping times is infinity

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I encountered the following problem:

**Problem:** Assume that $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a counting process and $(T_j)_{j\geq 1}$ be the corresponding jumping times. If $$\mathbb E[N_t]<+\infty$$ for all $t\geq 0$ then $$\lim_{j\rightarrow +\infty} T_j=+\infty.$$

**Clue:** What I know is that
$$\{N_t\geq n\}=\{T_n\leq t\}$$
But I don't know how to apply this relation to above problem.

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $N_t \geq 0$, you have

$$\mathbb{E}\left(N_t\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0} P\left(N_t \geq n\right),$$

whence the sum

$$\sum_n P\left(T_n\leq t\right) < \infty$$

by the identity you mention. By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the probability that infinitely many events of the form $\left\{T_n\leq t\right\}$ occur is zero, i.e., you can have only finitely many $T_n$ that are less than $t$. This holds for any $t$, so it must be the case that $T_n\rightarrow\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Using Borel-Cantelli  is indeed a great idea, thank you so much for your answer!